# Nginx rewrite a folder with exclude

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i am working on nginx webserver.

I want to redirect all urls inside folder1 www.site.com/folder1/ but not the subfolder1 www.site.com/folder1/subfolder1

I created these rules to nginx configuration but no luck.

> location = /folder/subfolder {
>
> }
>
> location /folder {
>
> rewrite ^/folder(.*) www.redirect.com permanent;
>
> }

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here's a refined answer including some of the comments I've read plus one of mine,
 to be able to access the assets inside the subfolder I added the `try_files`, and the `301` redirect in all other urls was added for the redirection.

```
location /folder/subfolder {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /folder {
    return 301 $scheme://example.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new set of rules should be as follows. I am assuming that valid file hits are okay (i.e. the user knew the file). If you do not want this behaviour, replace try_files with the content of the @rw block:

```
location /folder {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rw;
}
location @rw {
    rewrite ^/folder/([^\/]*) http://www.redirect.com/ permanent;
}
```

These should work.

Comment: Please give me more specific example.

i want all the urls inside www.test.gr/folder/ to be redirected to another static url like home page but the url www.test.gr/folder/subfolderx continues work without redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "=" because that's for "exact" match. So it only matches the folder itself, and a request for "/folder/subfolder/a_file.html" won't match that block. Also you need to add $scheme in your rewrite rule. And if you just want to redirect to the home page (http://www.redirect.com), you can remove the "$1" part.

```
location /folder/subfolder {

}

location /folder {

  rewrite ^/folder(.*)$ $scheme://www.redirect.com$1 permanent;

}
```

Comment: With this solution the exclude folder rule does not work. It gives me 404 not found

Comment: Are you serving static files under "/folder/subfolder"? You need to put a "root" directive inside it to tell nginx where to find the file. See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root. If you add more information on the file locations, I can tell you how to do that.